# Premature end of script headers при больших POST запросах

Tags: linux, apache, laravel, nginx

Имею стек вида nginx->proxy_pass->docker->apache2. При сохранении относительно больших запросов POST форм (Content-Length:10604) + редирект (owlAdmin для laravel, может кто в курсе) вываливается 500 Premature end of script headers. В этом примере в текст поле целая статья. если уменьшить ее до пары строк, то все сохраняется успешно.Менял версии php. Пытался различны диррективы добавлять в apache конфиги и подключать его как fastcgi. Но ничего не помогло. Что то у меня идеи закончились. МОжет кто подскажет чего? Сам я слабоват в админстве, может чего простейшего не вижу?

Comment: 500 - ошибка сервера. И ошибка *Premature end of script headers*  озанчает, что сервер получил не полный набор заголовков. Почитайте https://novall.net/errorsol/reshenie-apache-error-premature-end-of-script-headers.html возможно один их предложенных способов вам поможет

Comment: Это я все видел и пробовал. я увеличил в nginx размер передаваемых заголовков до 256kb думая что они приходят не полностью. но ничего  не помогло. апач не может ограничивать размер заголовков? и вообще, разве form data это заголовок, а не тело?  для тела post_max_size => 50M.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipart/form-data